# (R) How do I make a stacked bar chart using ggplot2 with proportion as the y-axis instead of count?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart with proportions as the y-axis instead of count. Everytime I try to execute, it greys out the graph and gets rid of the stacked feature.

Using the following code:

```
ggplot(data = gss_sm, aes(x = bigregion)) +
   geom_bar(aes(fill = religion), position = "dodge")
```

I get:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNORW.png)

I'd like to get proportion on the y-axis. I've tried the following:

```
ggplot(data = gss_sm, aes(x = bigregion, y = ..prop.., group = 1)) +
   geom_bar(aes(fill = religion), position = "dodge")
```

That gets me:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJBu.png)

How can I retain the color and dodged stacked bar chart in the latter.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It is best practice here to provide a minimal reproducible example, and it increases the chance of getting a good answer. I can not reproduce your code because I do not have your data. See this helpful post on reproducible examples for some options: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example.
Regarding your question: Do you want percentages relative to the total sample, or relative within each region?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input. The data is the gss_sm dataset in the socviz package in R. I'd like the percentages of the total sample.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here.  You could use `group=religion` in which case, the proportions will sum to 1 within each religion across the different regions.  Here's an example with the `credit_data` from the `modeldata` package.  In the example, `Marital` would be like `bigregion` and `Status` would be like `religion` in your code.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(modeldata)
library(dplyr)
data(credit_data)

credit_data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Marital)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Marital, y = after_stat(prop), group=Status)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Status), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

If, instead, you want the proportions of `religion` within each `bigregion`, you could aggregate the data first then plot the aggregated values directly. In this example, the proportions sum to 1 within `Marital` rather than within `Status`.

```r
credit_data %>% 
  group_by(Marital, Status) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  group_by(Marital) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Marital, y=pct, fill=Status)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>